# Error getting access token Lightning Experience Configuration Converter: Visualforce Pages

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components, access

What is this error and how can I avoid it?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: I'd put a Salesforce support case in. It is something that is in beta so it's possible there's some issues. It works fine for me, but I'm not sure there will be much out there to answer this without just guessing.

Comment: Thanks. I can only guess it's an authentication problem or something to do with dependencies. This didn't solve every case but making sure that all dependencies check this box: "Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app." 

On the other hand, maybe it was just trying it several times in a row... 
It's too late for SF to hide behind "beta." LEX goes out tomorrow.

Comment: I wasn't clear, the specific tab "Visualforce Pages" is in BETA with regards to this tool which is to help aid the transition to LEX.

Comment: Granted, but as I griped: Nothing should be in "Beta" 1 day before LEX from a company that made 13.28 billion USD (2019). Incidentally the problem "fixed itself."

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to fix itself after restarting / reconnecting / re-logging in.
If that still doesn't work, contact support.